# Dimension of $ U'\subset V^*$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional real vector space and let $U$ be a subspace of $V$.

Let $U':= \lbrace  \xi \in V^* , \xi(v) = 0 , \forall v \in U\rbrace$.

How can we prove that dim $ U' = $ dim $ V - $ dim $U$ ?

Comment: It would be worth a mention that $V^*$ denotes the dual of $V$, real linear functionals on $V$.  A larger omission is some *context* for your Question.  See [this note about the importance of context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) in asking a good Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to give you an idea and you fill in the details. Let $W$ be a subspace of $V$ such that $U \bigoplus W = V$. Let $\{e_1, \cdots, e_n\}$ be the basis of $U$ and $\{ e_{n+1}, \cdots, e_{n+m}\}$ the basis of $W$ such that $\{ e_1, \cdots, e_n, e_{n+1}, \cdots, e_{n+m}\}$ is the basis of $V$. Let $\{ f_1, \cdots,f_n, f_{n+1}, \cdots, f_{n+m} \}$ be the basis of V*, which is such that $f_i(e_j) = \delta_{ij}$. If $\xi \in U', $ $\xi(u) = 0, \,\,\ \forall u \in U$ (I imagine you mean that in the definition of $U'$). Then if $v \in V$, $v = u+w \in U \bigoplus W $. Thus

$$\xi(v) = \xi(u+w) = \xi(u)+\xi(w) = \xi(w) = \xi \left( \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+m}w_i e_i \right)= \sum_{j = 1}^{n+m}\alpha_j f_j \left( \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+m}w_i e_i \right) = \sum_{j = n+1}^{n+m}\alpha_j f_j \left( \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+m}w_i e_i \right)  =  \sum_{j = n+1}^{n+m}\alpha_j f_j \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_i e_i+ \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+m}w_i e_i \right) = \sum_{j = n+1}^{n+m}\alpha_j f_j (u+v). $$
that is, the functionals of $U'$ only depend linearly on $\{f_{n+1}, \cdots, f_{n+m}\}.$ Then $\dim U' = m = (n+m) - n = \dim V - \dim U.$

If you already know, a more direct way to solve this is to note that $U'$ is the [orthogonal complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_complement) of $U$.

Comment: Yes, I meant $\xi(v)=0 , \forall v \in U$, I'll fix it. Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: you are welcome!